# Separate the UI and backend logic in SpringMVC : Introducing JS controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Is there any way to get the spring form values on to my JS controller.

create.jsp

```
<form:form action="create.html" method="post" commandName="student" >

Student-Name<form:input path="studentName"/>
Student-Branch<form:input path="studentBranch"/>
Student-Dept<form:input path="studentDept"/>

<input type="submit" value="create"/>

</form:form>
```

when submit button is clicked, this will move to spring controller to map this URL-(create.html)

StudentController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create.html")
    public String createStudent(Model model, @ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
        model.addAttribute("message", serviceFile.createStudent(student));
        return "message";
    }
```

Now to separate the UI and backend logic completely,want to insert JS-controller in between this JSP(create.jsp) and Spring-controller(StudentController.java).

What can be done is that, need to remove spring form from jsp and make it simple html form. And on click of submit need to call a js method where all the form field need to be extracted based on form id or name, then setting to json-object and finally need to send this json-object to backend-controller using AJAX But the disadvantage that could have with this technique, need to map all the form field manually in JS file and again forming a json object manually.

Strictly donot want to use angularJS, backbone, nodejS or any JS library.Just JS, jquery ajax should be enough.

Could some one suggest the better technique so that need not to do all this extracting and setting the things manually.

Comment: Sounds to me like this is a perfect candidate of a RestFul web service.  Create a service that gets what you need for form elements.  Build the form elements in JS using a loop.  The only manual work would be creating the object in Java.

Comment: but the problem of setting the form field to js controller and then creating the json object there, how could be solved ?